# I have 8 years of daily data. I want to graph all values per day of the week, per weeks in a year and per month in a year. How do I do that?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, data-visualization

I want to be able to visualize my data points per days of the week, per weeks in a year and per months. I was able to visualize my data per year. But when I adjust the code for Monthly and weekly, the x-axis remains as per year.

I have 8 years of hospital records. My data is organized into 2 columns. Column number 1 is my "dates" column starting from 2010-03-10 and ending at 2017-12-31. Column number 2 is my value column. This column lists if I've had a patient come in for treatment or not. The values in column 2 are 0 or x numbers. For example 0 meaning I've had no patients x meaning I've had x number of patients. When I try to graphically represent this data, it only counts the largest x number I've had per week.

```
df=pd.read_csv('Data 3.csv', parse_dates=["Dates"], index_col="Dates")
# create the plot space upon which to plot the data
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (10,10))

# add the x-axis and the y-axis to the plot
ax.plot(df.resample('Y').sum()['Total # Events'],color = 'blue')

# rotate tick labels
plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=45)

# set title and labels for axes
ax.set(xlabel="Years",
ylabel="Total # of Events",
title="Yearly Treatment Events from 2010-2017");
```

[Graph result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdVHs.jpg)

So I get the correct graphical figure. But when I change the (df.resample('Y').sum() to ('M') from ('Y') for monthly I get a graph that displays a yearly X-axis and values. How can I change this to get monthly X-axis and Weekly X-axis?

Comment: Can you provide sample data to perform some analysis?

As far as I can see, if you have dates, you can use datetime indexes and group your data as weekly, monthly and yearly by using which week, month or year a value belongs to and then sum them and then perform the plots. It shouldn't be that difficult.

If you provide me small sample of 2 years, I can show you how to do it. Maybe use Google Drive to share the sample data.

Comment: Sure sounds good. Here's a google drive for the data set. Thanks for the help!
  https://drive.google.com/file/d/16m_0tl3_MEzAQ7g5E02uZXQAkRiBt3WA/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Give me 5 mins, working on it.

Comment: So I've tried everything and the only solution I think is to use a different representation of your data for week and month wise. You can unstack your values and show multiple lines for each month of a year separately.

Visualization software like Qlik and other do show Month and Year just below that, somewhat like this: https://community.qlik.com/legacyfs/online/179822_2017-10-16%2011_08_33-Service%20Complaint%20Report%20-%20Dashboard%20_%20Sheets%20-%20Qlik%20Sense.png

But not sure if that's doable in Python. What you see in the above image, do you want something of that sort?

Comment: Yea I wanted something like that. I've done this before using MATLAB and I remember it was extremely tedious because I had to loop everything to get what I wanted. I was trying to avoid doing the same in Python. I posted my code on GitHub for you to look at. BTW thanks A LOT FOR ALL YOUR HELP SO FAR!!   https://github.com/3twezzy/Undergrad-Thesis-Data-Analysis-of-Emergency-Oncology-Program

Comment: See, one thing I am not able to understand here is, do you want to know how to get aggregated values for Months and Weeks and Year and not able to do it, or the issue is regarding only the plotting?

Because I wrote an answer before how to calculate aggregate values and realized maybe you are asking just for plot, so I removed that answer.

I am undeleting it; can you just tell me, if that's what you want or is it just about plotting only and the answer isn't related? In that case, I'll delete my answer. Let me know in the comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, as I had assumed, this was easy given the dates were available.

So first create new columns denoting which week, year and month a date belong to. For that you need to set Dates as index and parse_dates while reading the csv:

```
data=pd.read_csv('Data 3.csv',index_col='Dates',parse_dates=True)
```

Now you can create the three columns:

```
data['Week']=data.index.week
data['Month']=data.index.month
data['Year']=data.index.year
```

This will give you data like:

```
            Total # Events  Week  Year  Month
Dates                                        
2010-03-10               0    10  2010      3
2010-03-11               4    10  2010      3
2010-03-12               0    10  2010      3
2010-03-13               0    10  2010      3
2010-03-14               0    10  2010      3
2010-03-15               0    11  2010      3
2010-03-16               0    11  2010      3
2010-03-17               0    11  2010      3
2010-03-18               2    11  2010      3
2010-03-19               0    11  2010      3
```

Rather than sharing whole code for you, I'll just show the Year output and how it works, rest I hope you can do by yourself, or you won't learn anything that way.

So the next step is:

```
Yearwise=data.groupby(by=('Year')).sum()['Total # Events']
```

And that's it, plot it:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(14,10))
Yearwise.plot()
```

And the graph as you have shared too, is:
[image]

Remember, for Month wise, you'll need Year and Month together for grouping or it will end up grouping all the same numbered months together. What I mean is something like this-

```
by=('Year','Month'))
```

Rest I am sure you can figure it out on your own. Still if you're getting error, let me know.

Comment: oh, awesome thanks for the help. I'll let you know how this goes!!

Comment: Oh you wanted this only? Haha, I made this like an hour back but then removed it thinking you are having issues with plots only.

Let me know if you aren't able to produce codes for them.

Comment: It worked completely fine. Now I'm just figuring out how I can label the x-axis as str names for months and weekday. Appreciate all the help though, THANKS!!

Comment: You're welcome bud and good luck with the naming part, that's kinda tricky, trust me.

Btw... Qliksense is free to use, you can download that and work with your data, exact same way I showed you the graph in the comments above. But still, have fun and Happy New Year mate. :D

Comment: Will definitely check Qliksense out. Happy new years to you too bud. :D

Answer (score 0):

Following the guide on matplotlib.org entitled ["Date tick labels"](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/date.html), I suggest playing around with these parameters:

```
# format the ticks
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(years)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(yearsFmt)
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(months)
```

Try for example adding only this line to your code after `ax.plot()`:

`ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(months)`

Bear in mind that although you are resampling your data, it is not changing the start or end dates. Your graph will look very similar except for it will now be smoother; it will not have 7 points but 7 * 12 points.